# How to use numpy.savez inside a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to use `numpy.savez` inside a loop so that I can directly save the array inside a file and save ram memory as I am dealing with huge data sets. Each iteration perfroms some work on the arrays, My idea is to stack the resulting array from each iteration on to previous arrays inside the npz file.

```
import numpy as np
a= [2,3,4]
b= [5,6,7]
steps=10
for n in range(steps):
 a=a*3
 b=b*4
np.savez('filename.npz', a=a, b=b)
```

But when I load the file, only the arrays from the last iteration is available. I know that the file is getting overwritten in each iteration, but is there a way I can stack all arrays inside the file?

Comment: What do you think `numpy.savez()` is for? _save the array inside a file and save ram memory as I am dealing with huge datasets_ Can you share your actual program?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,3,4])
b = np.array([5,6,7])
steps = 10
```

Then, in order to save a different file with each iteration (inside the loop), you use `format`:

```py
for i in range(steps):
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 3
    np.savez('filename{:03}.npz'.format(i), a=a, b=b)
```

To load:

```py
data = np.load('filename009.npz')
print(data['a']) # [118098 177147 236196]
print(data['b']) # [295245 354294 413343]
data2 = np.load('filename004.npz') 
print(data2['b']) # [1215 1458 1701]
print(data2['a']) # [486 729 972]
```

You could even use something as crazy as timestamps!

```py
from datetime import datetime

for _ in range(steps):
    a = a * 3
    b = b * 3
    np.savez('filename-{}.npz'.format(datetime.now().isoformat(sep='_', timespec='auto')), a=a, b=b)
```

The result is:

```
filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.013775.npz  filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.017066.npz
filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.014601.npz  filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.017710.npz
filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.015249.npz  filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.018611.npz
filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.015946.npz  filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.019326.npz
filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.016516.npz  filename-2020-01-24_00:02:42.019864.npz
```